# Как правильно написать "Спасибо вам огромное за ваш вклад в нашего ребёнка"?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно написать "Спасибо вам огромное, за ваш вклад, в нашего ребёнка"?

Comment: а в ребенка что-то вкладывали? может "за ваш вклад в развитие нашего ребенка"?

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сказал:

> Спасибо Вам огромное за вклад в **развитие нашего ребёнка.**

или же

> Спасибо Вам огромное за вклад в **развитие и воспитание нашего ребёнка.**

или же

> Спасибо Вам огромное, что вложили частичку своей души в нашего ребёнка.

Т.е. уточнить *что вложили* или *во что вложили*. Иначе звучит слишком неконкретно и режет слух.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо вам огромное за ваш вклад в нашего ребёнка. Запятые тут не нужны. Хотя лучше выразиться так: Спасибо огромное за ваш вклад в нашего ребёнка.